# Custom Object parameters within Jobs using Quartz-scheduler

Tags: java, scheduled-tasks, quartz-scheduler, job-scheduling

I am testing out Quartz to schedule a job. However the job contains 3 non-serializable parameters.

I have created a sample application below indicating how I am implementing the functionality. Does anyone know how I can use custom objects as parameters using Quartz?

Below is the trigger which schedules the job, I have commented the area which is giving me issues.

```
public class Trigger {

public void run() throws Exception {

    SchedulerFactory sf = new StdSchedulerFactory();
    Scheduler sched = sf.getScheduler();
    Date startTime = DateBuilder.nextGivenSecondDate(null, 15);


    JobDetail job = newJob(SimpleJob.class)
            .withIdentity("job6", "group1")
            .build();

    SimpleTrigger trigger = newTrigger()
            .withIdentity("trigger6", "group1")
            .startAt(startTime)
            .withSchedule(simpleSchedule()
                    .withIntervalInSeconds(60)
                    .repeatForever())
            .build();

    Date ft = sched.scheduleJob(job, trigger);

    TestObject testObject = new TestObject();

    // This is the part giving trouble!
    job.getJobDataMap().put(SimpleJob.test,testObject);

    sched.start();
}
```

}

Here is the job I am looking to schedule.

```
public class SimpleJob implements Job {

public static final TestObject test = null;

public SimpleJob() {

}

public void execute(JobExecutionContext context) throws JobExecutionException {

    test.saySomething();
}
```

}

And finally, the TestObject class.

```
public class TestObject {

public TestObject() {

}

public void saySomething() {

    System.out.println("Test Object initialized");
}
```

}

Please notice, I am only looking for a way to get Quartz to allow non-serializable objects to be used as a paramater (please do not comment on the actual task or job that is being carried out above)

I have also tried implementing the Serializable interface for the TestObject aswell, and no joy.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks you.

Comment: Have you considered dependency injection with Guice? http://markalcalaramos.blogspot.com/2009/11/quartz-and-google-guice.html -- http://99soft.github.com/guartz/

Comment: Hello! Thanks for your comment! I Have decided to use standard java timers, seems to have gotten the job done nicely!

Answer (score 10):

Implement your own [JobFactory](http://quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.2.0/org/quartz/spi/JobFactory.html). It will customize the underlying Job injecting any properties you need.

```
class MyJobFactory extends SimpleJobFactory {
    @Override
    public Job newJob(TriggerFiredBundle bundle, Scheduler Scheduler) throws SchedulerException {
        SimpleJob job = (SimpleJob) super.newJob(bundle, Scheduler);
        job.setTestObject(testObject);
        return job;
    }
}
```

You still need to use JobDetails to inform the class of your job, and you need to modify the scheduler to use your factory.

```
Scheduler scheduler = new StdSchedulerFactory().getScheduler();
scheduler.setJobFactory(new MyJobFactory());
scheduler.scheduleJob(jobDetail, trigger);
scheduler.start();
```

Comment: Your solution gave a great insight to look into Quartz API. By default, Quartz job doesn't work with `@Autowired` job instance as quartz uses class name to create instance and thus no instance variable are available with D.I out of box. Now I was able to use autowired instances with your solution! Thanks.